# Explicit Intent in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, android-intent, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to start an explicit intent from a Titanium Android app? I need to open the evernote new note window with some text passed into it. Is this possible in Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Ti.Android.Intent

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.Intent-object.html.

I think you can specify the className as evernote app id (com.evernote), and pass the text using `putExtra()`